# How to get Total Sum of one column after multipling with other column values

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

[take a look at this Database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa7Cc.png)

There are two different columns, i want to multiply column "Purchase" value with Column "Stock". and then want to Sum of all answers. As per example, first row answer is 6600 and second row answer is 4500, i want total after multiplication and sum.

Tried this code: but getting 0 as result.

```
$purchase_sum = Stock::All()->sum('purchase' * 'stock');
```

Using Laravel eloquent method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your code, and indicate where you're having difficulty.

Comment: question updated. please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either multiply and sum the values using an SQL query ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)):

```
$total = DB::table('stock')->selectRaw('purchase * stock AS total')->sum('total');
```

Or you can use a reducer on your collection ([documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-reduce)):

```
$total = Stock::all()->reduce(function ($total, $item) {
    return $total + ($item->purchase * $item->stock);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help i cant vote up but thumbs up for you

Comment: @CricketPSL I have added thumbs up for fubar on your behalf.